# Web attacks from a herokuapp.com address -- how to stop

Tags: security, websecurity

I am not a Heroku customer, just a plain old user out there.

But, I am getting a steady stream of web attacks from a herokuapp.com address. They are being blocked by my security software (Norton), but (a) they are affecting performance on my system; (b) if my security is off even for a moment, I am afraid I will get infected.

What can I do to stop the attacks. Can I get Heroku to stop them? Is there a number to call to report this? Here's the data...

```
IPS Alert Name -- Web Attack: JSCoinminer Website
Attacking computer -- thrillngos.herokuapp.com (54.243.125.28.443) 
Source address -- thrillingos.herokuapp.com (54.243.125.28)
```

Answer (score 0):

I signed up with Heroku and submitted a support ticket. That seems to be the way to get their attention, as the abuse team responded and reported shutting this app down within a couple of hours.

Unfortunately, the attacks continue from a variety of herokuapp addresses. I have informed them and am awaiting further responses